# Using a keystore with curl

Tags: shell, curl, openshift, redhat

I would like to execute the below curl command and specify my own key store.

I tried using --cacert option and specified the path of the cacert jks.

```
curl --ssl-reqd --url 'smtp://mailhost.myorg.com:587' --user 'usrid:pwd' --mail-from 'fromaddr@myorg.com' --mail-rcpt 'toaddr@myorg.com' --upload-file mail.txt -vv --cacert /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.272.b10-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

But it resulted in an error.

```
curl: (77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

Answer (score 5):

As Amit quoted, `curl --cacert` requires a file in PEM format -- but the Java `cacerts` file is in JKS format, which is massively different.

You can convert the certs from JKS format to PEM format with a script, something like:

```
jks=/usr/lib/jvm/$javaversion/jre/lib/security/cacerts
for c in $(keytool -keystore $jks -storepass changeit -list | awk -F, '/trustedCert/{print $1}'); do 
  keytool -keystore $jks -storepass changeit -exportcert -alias $c -rfc
done >pemfile
# for Java9 up use -cacerts instead of -keystore $jks
```

which *maybe* makes this marginally on-topic for SO, since your Q isn't about programming at all. Instead of doing *all* the certs you could do a selected one, or few, that are needed for the connections you want to make and validate.

But for RedHat (as tagged) this isn't necessary. In RedHat (and RH-based) Open JDK packages `JRE/lib/security/cacerts` is actually a symlink to `/etc/pki/java/cacerts` which is supplied by a different package `ca-certificates.noarch` -- which also supplies the *same* certs already in PEM format in `/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem` so you could use that directly (in spite of the name appearing singular it actually contains, or rather links to a file containing, *many* certs) AND in NSS format in `/etc/pki/nssdb/*` which is what the RH package of `curl` uses by default. Thus your `curl` already by default uses the same certs you can get from the Java `cacerts` file, so this effort accomplishes nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

when using `--cacert`  you need to specify the certificate  - e.g - `/tmp/ca.crt`

From the [docs](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html):

> --cacert (HTTPS) Tells curl to use the specified certificate file to verify the peer. The file may contain multiple CA certificates. The
> certificate(s) must be in PEM format. If this option is used several
> times, the last one will be used.
>
> --capath (HTTPS) Tells curl to use the specified certificate directory to verify the peer. The certificates must be in PEM format, and the
> directory must have been processed using the c_rehash utility supplied
> with openssl. Certificate directories are not supported under Windows
> (because c_rehash uses symbolink links to create them). Using --capath
> can allow curl to make https connections much more efficiently than
> using --cacert if the --cacert file contains many CA certificates. If
> this option is used several times, the last one will be used.

So, if you specify `--cacert`, the CA certs are stored in the specified file. These CA certificates are used to verify the certs of remote servers that cURL connects to.

The `--capath` option is used to specify a directory containing the CA certs rather than a single file.

Comment: Java `cacerts` _is_ a file, but not in PEM format.